# Where is the best place to setup logger in Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to add a handler for root logger in scrapy project. It should takes the settings from settings.py file and work for all spiders. How would be better to implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using Default Logging**

You can look for the settings here: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html#logging-configuration

You can configure the settings file and it should work for all the spiders.

**Using Your Own Logging**

Scrapy now uses default Python logging mechanism. So you should be able to do this:

```
import logging
logging.getLogger().addHandler(<YourCustomHandler>)
```

Put the code in a file that is loaded when scrapy starts, may be in the settings file or `__init__.py` file.

Comment: Yes, but what if i want to write custom handler for logger which should take settings from settings.py file? Where should i place the code? Would extensions be a right place for it?